# Unable to read state updated by useReducer hook in context provider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am using `useReducer` hook to manage my state, but it seems like I have a problem with reading updated state in my context provider.

My context provider is responsible to fetch some remote data and update the state based on responses:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import useAppState from './useAppState';


export const AppContext = React.createContext();

const AppContextProvider = props => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useAppState();

  const initialFunction = () => {
    fetch('/some_path')
      .then(res => {
        dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_STATE', res });
      });
  };

  const otherFunction = () => {
    fetch('/other_path')
      .then(res => {
        // why is `state.stateUpdated` here still 'false'????
        dispatch({ type: 'DO_SOMETHING_ELSE', res });
      });
    }
  };

  const actions = { initialFunction, otherFunction };

  useEffect(() => {
    initialFunction();
    setInterval(otherFunction, 30000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ state, actions }}>
      {props.children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  )
};

export default AppContextProvider;
```

and `useAppState.js` is very simple as:

```
import { useReducer } from 'react';


const useAppState = () => {
  const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'UPDATE_STATE':
        return {
          ...state,
          stateUpdated: true,
        };
      case 'DO_SOMETHING_ELSE':
        return {
          ...state,
          // whatever else
        };
      default:
        throw new Error();
    }
  };


  const initialState = { stateUpdated: false };

  return useReducer(reducer, initialState);
};


export default useAppState;
```

The question is, as stated in the comment above, why is `state.stateUpdated` in context provider's `otherFunction` still `false` and how could I access state with latest changes in the same function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## `state` will never change in that function

The reason `state` will never change in that function is that `state` is only updated on re-render. Therefore, if you want to access `state` you have two options:

1. `useRef` to see a future value of `state` (you'll have to modify your reducer to make this work)

```js
const updatedState = useRef(initialState);
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  let result;
  // Do your switch but don't return, just modify result

  updatedState.current = result;
  return result;
};

return [...useReducer(reducer, initialState), updatedState];
```

2. You could reset your `setInterval` after every state change so that it would see the most up-to-date state. However, this means that your interval could get interrupted a lot.

```
const otherFunction = useCallback(() => {
  fetch('/other_path')
    .then(res => {
      // why is `state.stateUpdated` here still 'false'????
      dispatch({ type: 'DO_SOMETHING_ELSE', res });
    });
  }
}, [state.stateUpdated]);

useEffect(() => {
  const id = setInterval(otherFunction, 30000);
  return () => clearInterval(id);
}, [otherFunction]);
```

Comment: @errata If the answer is working out for you, don't forget to mark it as the answer.

Comment: Hey, sorry, didn't have a chance to try this out earlier. I went with the first approach, seems easier to implement in my use case, however, I still don't see updated state in the scope of `otherFunction()` from my example, but I do see it outside of its scope. I have to admit that I don't quite understand why is that the case, do you? I should use `useAppState()` in the same way in my context provider, right?

Comment: Did you use `updatedState` the third variable returned from `useAppState`? And yeah your context provider should be the same

Comment: Ah, right, I knew it was something trivial like that. Got it now, thanks a lot for answer and all explanations!

Comment: Really glad you share this answer! Your first option really saved me a lot of time and effort. Thanks!